# vue3 Component and props reactivity

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have this piece of code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CompA :value="valComputed" @change=onChange/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue';

export default {
  components: {
    CompA,
  },
  setup() {
    const amount = ref(0);

    const valComputed = computed(() => amount.value);

    const onChange = (data) => {
        if (data > 10)
        {       
            amount.value = data;
        }
        else {
            amount.value = 0;
        }
    };

    return {
      valComputed,
      onChange,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

CompA:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>CompA</h2>
    <p>Value received from the parent: {{ value }}</p>
    <button @click="emitValue">Emit Value</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineEmits } from 'vue';

export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    defineEmits('change');
    const emitValue = () => {
      emit('change', 9);
    };

    return {
      emitValue,
    };
  },
};
```

As you can see it in some cases I don't update the amount ref from the event. and in this case I would want CompA to have the correct, unupdated value.
How should I do this? as long as I don't change the amount ref with a new value, the prop is not updated

Comment: Do you mean if you emit 9, that the child value should be 9 regardless of the parent value?  It shouldn't be a prop then. Props are meant to bind values from the parent to a child.  Just use a child-only data variable.  You can still emit to the parent without there being a prop involved.

Comment: I mean that since 9 is smaller then 10 amount ref will not be updated
and should reflect in the child its value - 0

Comment: testing your code, that's exactly what happens.  [Vue Playground](https://shorturl.at/cER68).  With initial value 20, emit 9, the amount value updates to 0.  The 0 is reflected in the child.

Comment: I did have to correct for typos and other mistakes (e.g. `defineEmits` is not used with `setup()` function)

Comment: I'm talking about a case where the value remains the same. initial value 0, changes to 0.
and sorry about the mistakes.. I asked chatGPT to generate this code and manually changed it a bit 

Comment: I don't understand. If initially 0, and emitting 9, amount value is then assigned 0.  There wouldn't be any change seen in the child (0 to 0) but the logic still happens. What exactly are you expecting in that case?

Comment: I tried to give a minimal example as much as I could but maybe it was not good enough...
Ignore my example.
a new example, the child component prop updates its value to 10.123.
emit to parent 10.123.
parent sets its own value to 10.12 (it rounds the number) and this value goes to the child prop as well.
Now this happens again and the parent value does not actually updates. it goes from 10.12 to 10.12.
so the child does not update.
Ill try to create a code that does that.

Comment: The confusing part is when you say the child does not update.  **WHY** should it update if no value is changing?  As you say, the child value is 10.12 like the parent, it emits the exact same value as before... no value is updating.  What do you expect should change? You keep explaining the result, which makes sense to me, but not what you believe _should_ happen, which I'm not understanding.

Comment: I'll try to give a good example later
I dont have much time now